# In python, any way to automatically run functions as soon as a class is defined?

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I am developing a class.  The class-level data it will need is going to be relatively complex.  To save typing and minimize mistakes, I would like to define a good bit of this data through functions.  Also, I would like to make this data available to the user even if they aren't ready to instantiate the class.  So, I wonder, is there a way to get these functions to run automatically as soon as the class is defined?  As an example, I want something like

```
import numpy as np    

def class foo:

        @this_should_run_before_instantiation
        def define_bar:
            bar = np.range(100)

       @this_should_also_run_before_init
       def define_something_really complicated:
            bleh = # something that is too complicated for a single line or lambda

        def __init__(self):
            # etc.
```

So then the user can do something like

```
>>>from foopackage import foo
>>>foo.bar
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  ... #etc.
>>>foo.bleh
< whatever bleh is ... >
```

Comment: note, the way you wrote `define_bar` it wouldn't *do* anything except define a local variable that is immediately discarded

Comment: So, the most sane way to do this is to write a function, `def build_class(..)` that calls all your individual functions in whatever order you need, then right after your class definition, you call: `foo.build_class()` explicitly.

Comment: To automatically run as soon as a class is called is exactly what `def __init__` is  for

Comment: @PeterPrescott nope, that's when and whenever an instance is created

Comment: I know I haven't seen your code, but something smells to me. Maybe take a step back and take a high-level look at your architecture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sane / simple way to handle this is *for you the author of the class to do this explicitely*. So something like:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod # don't have to be but will likely benefit from being classmethods...
    def _define_something_really_complicated(cls):
        ...
    @classmethod
    def _define_something_else_really_complicated(cls):
        ...
    @classmethod
    def _build(cls):
        cls._define_something_really_complicated()
        cls._define_something_else_really_complicated()
        ...
    def __init__(self):
        ...

Foo._build() # where your module is defined.
```

Then whenever a consumer does `import foo; my_foo_instance = foo.Foo()` it will already be built.

You could create a metaclass which inspects the class members for some tag and it will automatically do this, but honestly, the above makes everything very clear to me and to future readers of your class (best not to move initialization of variables into magical-seeming metaclass foo).

Comment: OK, I think I get it.  But ... and I'm probably showing my ignorance here ... what if my user doesn't import all the contents of the module?  Maybe they do `from foo import Foo` instead of `from foo import *`.  Will `Foo._build()` ever execute?

Comment: @bob.sacamento it isn't possible to import specific parts of a module. A module is always run in its entirety. Something like `from foo import Foo` is essentially syntactic sugar for `import foo; Foo = foo.Foo; del foo`

Comment: Well, it works!  Learn something new every day!  Thanks!

Comment: @bob.sacamento again, you can make something fancy using decorators/metaclasses, but unless you expect for that same pattern to be re-used many many times, I don't think it is worth the effort and opaqueness it adds to the code-base. Any competent developer who reads the above, even if they don't know any Python, will understand what is going on.That is sort of the motto i've been settling on recently. Try to write things so that someone who is a competent developer but not in this language would understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Class attributes are initialized when the class is defined. No function is needed.

```
import numpy as np    

class Foo:
    bar = np.range(100)
    def __init__(self):
        # etc.
```

If you want a function that you can call after import but before instantiating the class at all, you can define a class function.

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def initialize_bar(cls):
        cls.bar = np.range(100)
```

Then...

```
>>> from foopackage import Foo
>>> Foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'bar'
>>> Foo.initialize_bar()
>>> Foo.bar
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```

Comment: Nothing about the example use case suggests that.

Comment: Understood, but the arrays etc. I am dealing with are going to get much more complicated that something that can be defined in one line.  Hence my question.  I'll edit to make more explicit.

Comment: Well sure, but the OP explicitly states that "The class-level data it will need is going to be relatively complex. To save typing and minimize mistakes, I would like to define a good bit of this data through functions." So a charitable interpretation is they don't mean to simply define a single class attribute.

Comment: @bob.sacamento You can put arbitrary code inside a `class` statement. The body is evaluated, and any names that result from the code are turned into class attributes.

Comment: On a closer look at your example, it's possible you do just want a class function that you can call after importing the class, but before creating any instances of the class.

Comment: @chepner while I hesitate to say that you should have class-level variables that require many lines to create, if you *are* going to do that, I would say putting that logic in a/various function(s) makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#file Foo.py

import numpy as np

bar = np.range(100)

class foo:
    pass
```

Then

```
# file main.py
import Foo

b = Foo.bar
foo_instance = Foo.foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever code you include on the top level of the module will be executed at import time.

Normally it's just function and class declarations. But you can put any code at the top level:

```
# module1.py
def foo():
  return bar

A = 100
print('You just imported module1')
```

Then you can `import module1` and see the message printed, and `foo.A` to equal 100.

Executing code with side effects at import time is usually not the most brilliant idea; make sure you understand what you are doing, and why. (Otherwise, don't do it, and provide an initialization function.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this (variant 1)

```
def complex_data_calc():
    return range(42)

class Foo:
    bar = compex_data_calc()

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

or this (variant 2)

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return range(42)

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and call with

```
from foopackage import Foo
Foo.bar    # variant 1
Foo.bar()  # variant 2
```