# Class Level Constructor for the Python Class

Tags: python

I understand that `__init__()` is the constructor for an instance of the class. It is called whenever a class is instantiated. There is also the concept of class variables -- variables that belong to the class and shared by all instances. For example:

```
class A(object):
    a = 1
    b = [] #a and b are shared by all instances of class A
```

But the problem is that sometimes it takes more code to initialize `a` and `b` than the one lines showing above. Therefore there is a need for 'class level constructor.' I wonder, though, if there is such a thing.

Comment: You can use a metaclass, but it isn't necessary. Python class bodies can run arbitrary statements, or you can use class methods like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724810/in-python-any-way-to-automatically-run-functions-as-soon-as-a-class-is-defined

Comment: I've only ever used (custom) metaclasses once in nearly 20 years of writing Python, and did so for some codegen feature that was really just there to help me write the rest of the code _faster_ for a personal project. I agree strongly with @juanpa.arrivillaga that you should almost certainly just assign the values that need assigning rather than trying to pursue some architectural solution for purity's sake.

Comment: The class method in that post sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like

```
class A(object):
    # .......

var = input()
var += 10
# ecc.

A.b = var
```

Comment: The `__init__()` is an instance constructor. It is called every time a new instance is created. I would like a class level constructor, where, it is called once when the class object itself is created.

Comment: I mean that you can create an attribute from outside the class so that you can run whatever you want before (as I did above)